# How can I test an action with jest if this action has thunk and axios?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test using jest my action and reducer. I don't understand the problem please help.

This is my action:

```
import { GET_TEXT } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getText = (text) => dispatch => {
    let obj = {text: text};
    const productsAPI = "http://192.168.0.22:3000/getText";
    axios.post(productsAPI, obj)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            dispatch({
                type: GET_TEXT,
                payload: res.data,
            });
        })
}
```

and this is my **App.jest.test**:

```
import * as action from './store/actions/textAction';
import * as types from './store/actions/types';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';



const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
console.log("Llegue hasta aqui");
describe('async actions', () => {

  it('should dispatch actions of ConstantA and ConstantB', () => {
    const expectedActions = {type: types.GET_TEXT, payload: 'Hola'};

    const store = mockStore({})
    store.dispatch(action.getText('Hola'));

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
  })
})
```

Always throws an error `Error: Network Error`

What's happening?

Answer (score 3):

As you're using `axios`, consider using `moxios` rather than `fetch-mock`, to mock your network requests.

To use `moxios`, you simply install, and uninstall moxios before and after each test:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  moxios.install()
})

afterEach(function () {
  moxios.uninstall()
})
```

You can then provide a mock for a particular request URL, in your test as follows:

```
it('should dispatch actions of ConstantA and ConstantB', () => {

  const expectedActions = {type: types.GET_TEXT, payload: 'Hola'};

  // Mock an end point and response for requests to /test
  moxios.stubRequest('/test', {
    status: 200,
    responseText: 'the mocked result'
  })    

  const expectedActions = {type: types.GET_TEXT, payload: 'Hola'};

    const store = mockStore({})
    store.dispatch(action.getText('Hola'));

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)

 })
```

For more information on `moxios`, [see this link](https://github.com/axios/moxios)

Comment: Thanks apparently works but now in "Received;" says : Array[] , what is happening ? thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Deivbid great to hear it works - what do you mean by "in Recieved" ?